# Pass img path from client to server flask

Tags: python, html, flask

Im new to web development and especially Flask and python. I´m trying to create site where you can browse images and once you click on one, that image will be shown on another page called image.html. My issue is that i dont know how to pass the img src and then fetch it on the server side, and pass it back to the rendered template.

(The images are stored under /static folder)
app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response, redirect
import os


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/image/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def image(id):

    #fetch image based on id?
    return render_template('image.html', id=id)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<a href="/image/123">
    <img src="static/123.jpg" id="123" alt="" width="400" height="400">
</a>


{% endblock %}
```

image.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='{{ id }}') }}" id="123" alt="" width="400" height="400">

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @MaxPowers you mean i cannot accomplish this with flask alone?

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible to achieve your stated goal with Flask alone and you are already on a possible path to the solution.

The following routes are based on your code. In addition, all files within the static directory are listed in `index` and transferred to the template.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Alternatively use app.static_folder here!
    files = os.listdir(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'))
    return render_template('index.html', files=files)

@app.route('/image/<path:id>')
def image(id):
    return render_template('image.html', id=id)
```

In the template itself, you can then iterate over the list of file names and use [`url_for`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for) to refer to the second route and transfer the file name as a variable of the route, as well as to the file itself within the img element. See also ["Variable Rules"](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) and ["Static Files"](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/static/#static-files).
Within the anchors it is possible to simply enter the same information to refer to the picture. However, if you want to embed the image on another page as described, I recommend that you pass the full file name as the path.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  {% for file in files %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('image', id=file) }}">
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=file) }}" alt="{{ file }}" width="400" height="400" />
    </a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Since you are already within an expression for a code block for the `url_for` specification, you do not need any further curly brackets and you can simply pass the variable passed to the template as a filename.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=id) }}" width="400" height="400">
{% endblock %}
```

I would advise you to put all the images in a sub-folder so that it is easier to separate them from other files. The procedure remains the same, only the path details vary.

Since I think that you are also interested in uploading new images to the server, I recommend [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/) and [this](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask/page/0) tutorial. On the last mentioned page you will find what I think is an [excellent introduction](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) to the framework and helpful articles on various topics related to flask.

Comment: thank you this worked! But i would also like to accomplish to make the href in index dynamic so it passes the src (or something), so the corresponding picture can be rendered. Hopefully that´s clear otherwise let me know and i will try to explain better

Comment: @Simplyrdy I've revised my answer. If you have any further questions or problems, I will be happy to help you.

Comment: Thank you for the help i will try this solution. And i do need to read more about the framework so thanks for the tutorial as well!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem you can solve put a simple link in your index template to your image function ...

```html
<a href="{{url_for('.image', id=123)}}">
    <img src="static/123.jpg" id="123" alt="" width="400" height="400">
</a>
```